# La propiedad de CardView layout_width = "match_parent" no se toma en cuenta

Tags: android-studio, recyclerview, android-recyclerview, cardview

Estoy implementando una aplicacion donde muestro informacion de una base de datos en un RecyclerView y en el utilizo CardView (Este RecyclerView esta en un fragmento), mi problema es que el CardView no me respeta la propiedad "match_parent" como se muestra en la imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

mi codigo en  del CardView es este:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/cardView"  
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#e2e2e2"
        card_view:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        card_view:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        card_view:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Buscando en el foro encontre algunas preguntas relacionadas en donde decian que agregara un padre al CardView, al hacer me soluciona el problema pero eso hace que no tenga onclick cada elemento del ReciclerView y no entiendo porque.

Otra solucion que encontre fue agregar:

```
WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager)v.getContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        int width = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
        v.setLayoutParams(new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(width, RecyclerView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

Esto tambien me soluciono a medias ya que me quito el margen del CardView como se muestra en la imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

despues de eso intente agregarle margen al RecyclerView al inflar la vista pero fue un fracaso.

Se lo agradeceria mucho si alguien pudiera echarme una mano, gracias..

Answer (score 0):

En el método `onCreateViewHolder` de tu Adapter, seguramente tienes algo como esto:

```
    view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_participant,null,false);
```

Cambia el null por parent para que quede de la siguiente forma:

```
view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_participant,parent,false);
```